# crash when running in device-animation in iOS

Tags: ios

i have created a simple animation with 4 images..it runs in simulator but in device it gets crashed..
code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self flashOn:_myButton];


    NSArray *imageNames= @[@"jake_2.png",@"jake_4.png",@"jake_5.png"];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    NSMutableArray *images = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


    for (int i = 0; i < imageNames.count; i++)
    {
        [images addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:[imageNames objectAtIndex:i]]];
    }
        UIImageView *slowAnimationImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(160,95,86,193)];
        slowAnimationImageView.animationImages = images;
        slowAnimationImageView.animationDuration = 5;
        [self.view addSubview:slowAnimationImageView];
        [slowAnimationImageView startAnimating];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare slowAnimationImageView as retain property in header file like below -

```
@property(nonatomic,retain)  UIImageView *slowAnimationImageView;
```

Comment: it results in object cannot be nil'
*** First throw call stack:

Comment: Then its only retain issue , please check below my answer

Answer (score 0):

In .h file

```
@property(nonatomic,retain)  IBOutlet UIImageView * slowAnimationImageView;
```

In .m file

```
-(void)imageAnimation{
    self. slowAnimationImageView.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:    
                                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"jake_2.png"],
                                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"jake_4.png"],
                                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"jake_5.png"]],
                                            nil];
    self. slowAnimationImageView.animationDuration = 5.0f;
    self. slowAnimationImageView.animationRepeatCount = 0;
    [self. slowAnimationImageView startAnimating];

}
```

Comment: Let me know images name re same like `jake_2.png` , `jake_4.png` and `jake_5.png` Please double check it out @ManoChitraR

Comment: If not working then please add those images into `Images.xcassets` @ManoChitraR

Comment: images are same as given

Comment: @ManoChitraR Here I create simple demo for load multiple images https://www.dropbox.com/s/moa3itl600qkf3c/ImageAnimationDemo.zip?dl=0

Comment: tank u neon..i can run ur code and its fine..but in my code its same as before

Comment: @ManoChitraR May be image creation problem so please open that image via double click on image open into `Preview` -> `File` -> `Export...` -> `Give name of the image` -> **Select Format PNG** and those image add into project.

Answer (score 0):

In simulator the name are case in-sensitive. While in device the names are case sensitive. Everything in your code is perfect. Just check verify the file name of image.

Make sure it is exactly same in the code and actual file name. i.e. The image file bundled into application must have file name as "jake_2.png" and so for all the image files.

Answer (score 0):

I have checked by running your code with different Image names and it is not crashing for me on my device. you should try these steps that may help to solve out the issue

1. cross check you image names and check that you added in your bundle.
2. Just do product clean and try to run again.